# Equidistribution of $(2^nx)$, $x$ irrational

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I've run into a scenario where it would be extremely useful to know if, for $x$ irrational, the sequence $\{(2^nx)\}$ is equidistributed on in $[0,1]$, where $(\cdot)$ denotes the ``fractional part" of a number.  I've tried to show that this is true using Weyl's criterion to no avail.  I am not a number theorist in any way, and I am curious if anybody here knows how to show this, or if anybody here is aware of some tools that could be useful.

Comment: This is equivalent to $x$ being normal in base $2$. Almost all, but not all, irrational numbers have this property.

Answer (score 2):

Not always. The sum

$x=2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-4}+2^{-8}+...$

with the exponent doubling on each successive term is irrational, but $(2^nx)$ is not uniform as $n\to\infty$. It clusters around each negative-integer power of $2$ and around $0$.

The problem of identifying [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) in any base is highly non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you!  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I meant the measure of $\{x: (2^nx) \text{is equidistributed}\}$.  But I now realize that the wikipedia article you linked answers this question.